# Remove one of the same phrases

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove one of the same phrases in `.id p` dynamically by `$.each`, i tried as following code but this don't work for me and it removed all phrases in `.id p`:

How is it?

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/juyiwololi/

```js
$('.id p').each(function() {
    var item = $(this).text();
    alert(item);
    $('.id p').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == item
    }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="id">
   <p>John</p> //***//
   <p>Johny</p>
   <p>John</p> //***// //i want remove this
   <p>asas</p>
   <p>ddf</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So you're basically trying to remove only the duplicate values?

Comment: Why use `each` if you're going to use `filter`? I mean, it seems like you're solving this problem in the wrong place. In any case, you're using `each`, so `item` will get set to every paragraph's text, then you filter the paragraphs based on that text...